# I am creating a Basic authentication in Django Rest Framework in Django 2.1 version.But it shows '.authenticate() must be overridden' error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Settings.py**

> REST_FRAMEWORK = {
>       'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':('rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',),
>       'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',)
>   }

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Emp(models.Model):
    eid = models.IntegerField()
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sal = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ename
```

**admin.py**

> ```
> from django.contrib import admin
> from .models import Emp
> class AdminEmp(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     list_display = ['eid','ename','sal']
> admin.site.register(Emp,AdminEmp)
> ```

**serializers.py**

> ```
> from .models import Emp
> from rest_framework import serializers
> class EmpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Emp
>         fields = ('eid','ename','sal')
> ```

**views.py**

> ```
> from .serializers import EmpSerializer
> from .models import Emp
> from rest_framework import viewsets
> from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
> from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
> class EmpViewSet2(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
>     authentication_classes = (BaseAuthentication,)
>     permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
>     queryset = Emp.objects.all()
>     serializer_class = EmpSerializer
> ```

**app level urls.py**

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import url,include
> from .views import EmpViewSet2
> from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
> router = DefaultRouter()
> router.register('emp_viewset',EmpViewSet2,base_name='emp_viewset2')
> urlpatterns = [
> url(r'',include(router.urls)) ]
> ```

**Project level urls.py**

> ```
> from django.contrib import admin
> from django.urls import path,include
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
>     path('api/', include('Basic_Authentication_App.urls'))
> ]
> ```

**Username and password window**
[image]

**Django Rest Framework window** *but when i click on this link*
*"emp_viewset":"http://127.0.0.1:3499/api/emp_viewset/"*

[image]

it shows like below:
**NotImplementedError at /api/emp_viewset/**
*.authenticate() must be overridden.*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own authentication back-end. You can see an [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) from the official django documentation that explains in detail how to implement (i.e. override) the `authenticate` function.

Of course, if you want to provide your own permissions, you can [implement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends) a custom authentication back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Remove below code from views.py:-

```
authentication_classes = (BaseAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

everything will work properly.
and if you want to change permissions than just add in views.py

permission_classes = []

no need to add

authentication_classes

So the

permission_classes

in views.py will override the permission given in settings.py..

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

`authentication_classes = (BaseAuthentication,) permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` 
You are using `BaseAuthentication` instead of `BasicAuthentication`
that's the reason you are getting `NotImplementedError at /api/emp_viewset/ .authenticate() must be overridden` Error